# /dev/random but predictable?

Tags: linux, storage

If I want to do a quick test of some flash memory that I'm not sure is working correctly, the convenient ways to write data to it are either `/dev/random` or `/dev/zero`.

However, with `dev/random`, I have no idea what it wrote to check later, and `dev/zero` will always show zero. Because of that, I may miss a section of the flash that is not saving correctly and the read will return zero as well.

Is there anything that will give me, with the same convenience of the above, a predictable stream? Something like 1010101010 would work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe [badblocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Badblocks) is what you need. It will do all the work for you - namely, detect read, write and corruption errors.

Answer (score 2):

`yes "stuff" > /dev/sdX`

or

`yes "stuff" > file.txt`

and

`sudo dd if=file.txt of=/dev/sdX`

Comment: nice trick with `yes` :)